# PHP curl: Cannot archive files based on Date, get curl error: 1

Tags: php, curl, sftp

I'm trying to archive files in PHP using a curl statement. It runs fine when the file name is static, but gives me error code 1 when I try to add the date to the file name.

NOTE: the initial pull uses the same date format in the file name to pull the file but will not save it with the same name.
How do I get around this?

This works:

`system("curl -Y 1k -y 10 -u url:password\"ftps://ftp.test.com/folder/filename(" . $dt->format('Y-m-d') . ").csv\" -o /home/archive/public_html/static_filename.csv", $status);`

this does not:

```
<?php
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $dt->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $status = "";
    do {
        system("curl -Y 1k -y 10 -u url:password\"ftps://ftp.test.com/folder/filename(" . $dt->format('Y-m-d') . ").csv\" -o /home/archive/public_html/filename(" . $dt->format('Y-m-d') . ").csv", $status);

    } while ($status != 0);
    
    if($status != 0){
        echo 'Error';

    }else{
       echo 'Success';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Since you are piping a string to system (not sure why you'd do that? but anyway) this has little if anything to do with php. The output file argument is not quoted _and_ contains a space - that's syntactically invalid, the call to curl will fail. In future please debug to solve such problems (here meaning just dump the string to the terminal, attempt to execute that string - and read the error message) :).

Comment: Thanks, that was a syntax error when removing PI from the code. I still get the same error when the space is removed.

Comment: well, you will, yes. Because the next syntax error is there's an unescaped/unquoted string containing a `(` - please **just dump the string to the terminal, attempt to execute that string - and read the error message** :)

Comment: Ah, it was the ( . Thank you so much, I would have never thought that.